# GLUT mouse move , coordinates always on

Tags: c++, mouse, glut

How to get the mouse coordinates always, without click on mouse?

```
void mouseMove(int mx, int my) {

}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitWindowSize( x, y );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutCreateWindow( "Freetype OpenGL" );
    glutReshapeFunc( reshape );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMotionFunc(mouseMove);
    timer();
    glutMainLoop( );
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

[`glutMotionFunc()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node51.html) is called when the mouse moves within the window while one or more mouse buttons are pressed, and [`glutPassiveMotionFunc()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node51.html)  is called when the mouse moves within the window while no mouse buttons are pressed.

You probably want to use both of them, to cover all the cases.

Comment: I bring to the screen the values of the mouse on the axes, but they are updated only when I click on the button. The timer function is work good, constantly updated.